# Add/remove class routing when he was active Angular 2

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I want to add the done classes to the routing when I change it in another component:
For example: I am in step1(component) click "go to step 2" in navbar routing component step1 receives classes done

my navbar.html (component)

```
<li routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"  class="step"><a [routerLink]="['step1']">
          <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Miejsce i data</h4>
        </a></li>
        <li routerLinkActive="active" class="step disabled"><a [routerLink]="['step1']">
          <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Wybierz samochód</h4>
        </a></li>
```

my step1.html (component)

```
 <button (click)="goStep2()">go to step 2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You could set up a variable `step1Done = false` and when `goStep2()` is called, within that function set `this.step1Done = true` and then bind that value to a class in your html `[class.done]='step1Done`
2. you could handle all of that in the .ts component,
   use a template reference in your html `<div #myDiv>` get the element in your .ts file with `@ViewChild() myDiv;` and then in your `goStep2()` function add the class `this.myDiv.nativeElement.classList.add('done')`